# java tree class to XML through jRuby on rails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, xml, jruby

I have a custom Java Tree class (from [stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml),) that I am able to work with in JRuby on Rails.

What I am trying to figure out how to do is to output this tree class to XML through rails

The tree class describes a word tree derived from a parsed sentence. Each tree may have multiple child trees depending on the structure

Here is a simple example based off of the sentence "I am a robot":

```
Tree: Root
-Tree: Sentence
--Tree: Noun
---Tree: I
--Tree: Verb
----Tree: am
--Tree: Noun
---Tree: a
---Tree: robot
```

One important detail is that I don't need to store any of this in a database, so using ActiveRecord may not be the best choice.

Do you have any ideas about the best approach for this? I have read some ideas in tutorials, but I'm not sure what the best way for my case is, especially since I am very new to rails and don't yet understand 'the rails way'

EDIT:

Option 1: use the builder gem

Option 2: create an (activerecord?) wrapper class in ruby

Option 3: create a special to_xml function (in java?) for this class

Any other ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

I created a class in ruby that on initialization imports from the java tree object. I'm still trying to figure out how to structure it best, and I have not written a good to_xml class. though, on further reading, I think I will use JSON instead of xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create an [ActiveModel](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) class (part of Rails 3.0). You can decorate any object with ActiveModel and you get all the ActionPack goodness without having to be tied to a DB. You get to_xml and to_json for free.